# Disable property on media query

Tags: css

I made some website with pure html/css.

I defined overflow-y: scroll to some element when browser is full screen.

But when screen's width is less than 400px, I want to disable that. (like, overflow-y: none. But overflow-y doesn't have none)

Is there any solution about this?

Comment: you can try `initial` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nope. CSS property has initiallize?

Comment: I solved by `overflow: visible`. But is there any other solution? I don't know is it correct way.

Comment: yes visible is the default value is it should work .. but `initial` as value should also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Can use just ***overflow: auto;**

then it works fine  See Example.

```css
#overflowTest {
    background: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#overflowauto {
    background: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>overflow scroll</h2>
<div id="overflowTest">This text is really long and the height of its container is only 100 pixels. Therefore, a scrollbar is added to help the reader to scroll the content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </div>

<h2>overflow auto</h2>
<div id="overflowauto">This text is really long and the height of its container is only 100 pixels. Therefore, a scrollbar is added to help the reader to scroll the content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt property-on-media-query# laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </div>
```

You Can Learn more about Overflow Property https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

**--- Thank You ---**